# Join even on rows that are not in the first table

Tags: php, sql

I have two subqueries on which I am doing a join, first one returns following data:

```
array (size=110)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'scans' => string '7' (length=1)
      'bonus_points' => string '0' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-06-13' (length=10)
```

second one:

```
array (size=21)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'redeems' => string '1' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-06-13' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'redeems' => string '1' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-06-15' (length=10)
```

If I do a left join on those two like so:

`LEFT JOIN query2 ON query2.date=query1.date;`

I get:

```
array (size=110)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'scans' => string '7' (length=1)
      'redeems' => '1'
      'bonus_points' => string '0' (length=1)
      'date' => string '2017-06-13' (length=10)
```

Row with the date 2017-06-15 gets lost as the second query doesnt have the match with the first.

How can I get both rows returned? Like so:

```
array (size=110)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'scans' => string '7' (length=1)
          'redeems' => '1'
          'bonus_points' => string '0' (length=1)
          'date' => string '2017-06-13' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'scans' => null
          'redeems' => '1'
          'bonus_points' => null
          'date' => string '2017-06-15' (length=10)
```

Comment: You can do a `right join`. Most people prefer `left join` for readability; in which case you should swap your tables around.

Comment: @HoneyBadger then I will get only results from the second table not from the both

Comment: In that case you can do a `full join` (unless you happen to work with mysql, which doesn't support full joins. You'll need to `union` two queries if that's the case.)

Comment: Thanks I will look into the UNION

Comment: Be carful with `UNION`, it removes duplicates.  `UNION ALL` removes that behavior *(and overhead)*, but requires you to add a little more logic to one of your queries...   `FULL OUTER JOIN` == `LEFT JOIN` UNION ALL `RIGHT JOIN WHERE leftTable.id IS NULL`

Comment: @MatBailie actually union creates duplicates it doesn't join my rows. Can  you write an example of "union all" on my rows?